# Replacing part of string with prefix and suffix

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

```
$str = ' I love [123] and [124] at (456). I hate [234] and [235] at (123).'
```

I want to make it

```
$str = 'I love <a title="a">[123]</a> and <a title="b">[124]</a> at <a title="XX">(456)</a>. I hate <a title="c">[234]</a> and <a title="d">[235]</a> at <a title="ZZ">(123)</a>.'
```

Texts to replace with is with in braces () or [] and can be found from Table 1 or Table 2.

```
Table 1
123 | a
124 | b
234 | c
235 | d

Table 2
456 | XX
123 | ZZ
```

Current approach

```
$text=explode(' ', $text);
for ($i=0; $i<count($text); $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<count($table1Col1); $j++) {
        if ($text[$i] == $table1Col1[$j])
            $text[$i] = '<a href="#" title="'.$table1Col2[$j].'">'.$table1Col1[$j].'</a>';
    }
    for ($j=0; $j<count($table2Col1); $j++) {
        if ($text[$i] == $table2Col1[$j])
            $text[$i] = '<a href="#" title="'.$table2Col2[$j].'">'.$table2Col1[$j].'</a>';
    }
}
```

How to improve the code to skip not-required loop ?

Comment: So `[]` only applies to table1 and `()` to table2?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yup !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a way with one loop that I'll think on, but since the arrays have the same keys they can't be merged:

```
foreach($table1Col1 as $find => $repl) {
    $text = str_replace("[$find]",
                        "<a title=\"$repl\">[$find]</a>",
                        $text);
}

foreach($table1Col2 as $find => $repl) {
    $text = str_replace("($find)",
                        "<a title=\"$repl\">($find)</a>",
                        $text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, the [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) would be better here?

```php
$str = 'I love [123] and [124] at (456). I hate [234] and [235] at (123).';
$t1 = ['123'=>'a', '124'=>'b', '234'=>'c', '235'=>'d'];
$t2 = ['456'=>'XX', '123'=>'ZZ'];


$f1 = implode('|', array_map(fn ($k) => preg_quote($k), array_keys($t1)));
$f2 = implode('|', array_map(fn ($k) => preg_quote($k), array_keys($t2)));

$res = preg_replace_callback("/\[($f1)\]|\(($f2)\)/", function($m) use($t1, $t2) {
  // if first group has matched, then found key will be in `$m[1]`
  // if second group has matched, then found key will be in `$m[2]`
  $m1 = $m[1] ?? null;
  $m2 = $m[2] ?? null;
  if ($m1) {
    // use first table
    return '<a title="'.$t1[$m1].'">['.$m1.']</a>';
  }
  // use second table
  return '<a title="'.$t2[$m2].'">('.$m2.')</a>';
}, $str);
```

Result:

```
I love <a title="a">[123]</a> and <a title="b">[124]</a> at <a title="XX">(456)</a>. I hate <a title="c">[234]</a> and <a title="d">[235]</a> at <a title="ZZ">(123)</a>.
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the values in the string are present in the table, you could use an alternation `|` to capture each of the digits in 2 groups, and index in to arrays using the group value using [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
\[(\d+)]|\((\d+)\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kknVZX/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/ijbGY)

```
$str = ' I love [123] and [124] at (456). I hate [234] and [235] at (123).';
$table1Col1=["123" => "a", "124" => "b", "234" => "c", "235" => "d"];
$table1Col2 = ["456" => "XX", "123" => "ZZ"];
$pattern = "/\[(\d+)]|\((\d+)\)/";

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) use ($table1Col1, $table1Col2) {
    return sprintf('<a title="%s">%s</a>',
        array_key_exists(2, $match) ? $table1Col2[$match[2]] : $table1Col1[$match[1]]
        , $match[0]
    );
}, $str);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
 I love <a title="a">[123]</a> and <a title="b">[124]</a> at <a title="XX">(456)</a>. I hate <a title="c">[234]</a> and <a title="d">[235]</a> at <a title="ZZ">(123)</a>.
```

Comment: Your solution limits tables to using only numeric keys, and doesn't handle non-existing keys.

Comment: @Styx In the example data, the keys are numeric, and that is why it started with `Assuming all the values in the string are present in the table`

Comment: Right, sorry, didn't notice this line.

Comment: @Styx No prob, if there can be other chars then the pattern could be for example `\[([^][]+)]|\(([^()])\)`

Comment: Still think that searching for exact tables' keys is better. Though I like your using `sprintf`, didn't think about that :)

Comment: @Styx If the keys are not always there, then your answer would definitely be better.